# How to use instance of dynamically in java?

Tags: java

I have a string variable which stores the name of a class (e.g. String,Integer etc)

```
String type = "String";
```

I have an object which i need to check if it is an instance of the class whose name is stored in the string variable. How do I check it ?

```
if (object instanceof type){
   // Do something here
}
```

However, the above logic doesn't work as the variable type is not recognized as a class. So, how do I dynamically check if an object is an instance of 'type'.

Comment: You'd use [`Class#isInstanceOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance(java.lang.Object)) (and then just having a string with value `"String"` is not sufficient, because the classname is `java.lang.String`)

Comment: that's not the full name of a String. The full name would be java.lang.String

Comment: What are you actually doing? Why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the *fully qualified* name of the class, you can use `Class.forName("java.lang.String").isAssignableFrom(type)`.

If you don't have qualified names, you'll have to code out a mapping, something like this:

```
switch (typeName) {
  case "String": return type instanceof String;
  case "Integer": return type instanceof Integer;
  // et cetera
}
```

Comment: A quick addendum: read `typeA.isAssignableFrom(typeB)` as "is `typeA someVariable = someInstanceOfTypeB;` allowed?"

Comment: @0x150 Yes, it checks if that assignment is allowed. See the javadoc [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom(java.lang.Class)).

Comment: I know, I just wanted to point out a quick metaphor for the method, since I myself got quite confused about it a while ago.